# Undefined local variable or method `params` Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have the following controller RSpec test that should work however when I try to execute the below code:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')


describe UsersController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers #Include devise test helpers
  render_views # Render devise views

  describe "GET 'show'"

  before(:each) do
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @attr = {:initials => 'EU', :name => 'Example', :full_name => 'Example User',
             :email => 'user@example.com', :password => 'password', :password_confirmation => 'password'

             #@attr = User.all
    }
  end

  it 'should be successful when showing OWN details' do
    get :show, :id => @attr
    response.should be_success
  end

  it 'should find the correct user' do
    get :show, :id => @attr
    assigns(@attr).should == @attr
  end
end
```

However I am getting the following output: `Undefined locacl variable or method 'params' for RSPRC` I believe this set up should be correct.

Comment: Along with that failure is a stack trace.  What line of code does it indicate had the problem?

Comment: @WayneConrad I get the following output - http://i.imgur.com/xdY0JF4.png

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things going on here.

Your calling params within the before statement but where is the id ever set? No where in this code do I see where the user id is ever actually determined/found. You should set @user explicitly using either an id that you know exists or doing something such as User.first.

Then instead of calling

```
get :show, :id => @attr
```

you should be calling

```
get :show, :id => @user.id
```

Also I'm not sure why you need to include spec_helper twice. Line 2 should be able to be removed.

One more thing - assigns(@attr).should == @attr doesn't make any sense. It should be assigns(:attr).should == @attr. Otherwise you would be passing the value of @attr into the assigns method.

Comment: I made your changes but still get the same output - http://i.imgur.com/xdY0JF4.png

Comment: you error messages says: error in line 11. I guess :each is the cuplprit.

Comment: @Hartmut what should it be then

Comment: sorry, I misread the error message. It mentions line 11 but after that the error message also says `undefined local variable or method "params"`. Could you please post the new code? You said in the comments above that you changed it.